# How i can convert string to array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hi i have my data in a string 
like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pollId] => 2
            [poll] => new
            [cId] => 7
            [communityId] => 7
            [ansId] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => 7
                )

            [answer] => Array
                (
                    [0] => new1
                    [1] => new2
                )

            [vote] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 37
                    [1] => 36
                )

            [count] => 2
        )

)
```

i want to convert it to array.

Comment: I don't know but I am not getting you. You have array in to string and want to convert string to array, right

Comment: Which of those have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+php+array+to+javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best method for converting a PHP array to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387149/best-method-for-converting-a-php-array-to-javascript)

Comment: and what part does jquery have in this question? It's not clear for me

Comment: @Ass3mbler The part where jquery is confused for javascript I think.

Comment: @Hemlock It's really possible I think :) Let's see if he give us more info

Comment: I get him, the code snippet he posted is the exact string he wants to turn into an array.

Comment: @enthusiastic Do you have control over what creates the "array data in a string"? It looks like this is the result of a `print_r` when it should have been a `json_encode` as explained in the linked search.

Comment: yes you are right  nightcracker. i use ajax in codeigniter and my controller return this string and i want to use it in my jquery function. so how can i???

Comment: @Gorden ok i will convert it into JSON then how can i convert it  JSON to jquery array

Comment: @enthusiastic  You dont need to convert anything. If this is part of an Ajax call, use jQuery.parseJSON on the response. For anything else see the accepted answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>If you really have a *string* containing the text as quoted, you're going to have to either find or write a parser for it.</s>

It's not a *million* miles off JSON, and so you might get a leg up on your implementation (if you have to write one) from the two non-`eval` implementations of JSON parsers found on [Crockford's github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/). There's `json_parse.js`, which is a recursive-descent parser; and `json_parse_state.js` which is a state machine. In both cases, they parse JSON, not your example format, but my point is that as your example format isn't a million miles away from JSON, you can probably use them as a starting point.

**Update**: *(I'd added a comment about this, but it's better as part of the answer.)* I see from the comment stream on your question that you don't have to use this format, but instead can use JSON instead. In that case, you're in good shape — jQuery has JSON parsing built in, in its [`parseJSON` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON). That will accept a string containing JSON-encoded data and return a JavaScript object graph (which may or may not be an array, depending on what the JSON defines). If you retrieve the JSON via Ajax, jQuery will even parse it for you automatically and give you the resulting object graph as an argument to your `success` function, see [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) and [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON). [Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/eqafo3) I did for another question just earlier today. That loads the JSON found at the URL you'll see in the code, has jQuery automatically parse it, and accesses one of the properties of the resulting JavaScript object graph.

Comment: thanks T.J. Crowder. actually its not a JSON i simply return it from my controller in codeigniter framework.but i can convert it into JSON. if you have soluation to convert JSON into jquery array then please tell me. thanks in advance

Comment: @enthusiastic: I've updated the answer, since you've now said you can use JSON instead.

Comment: J.Crowder thanks. but its not working for me. i use success: function(msg){alert(msg.poll);});. its showing undefined

Comment: @enthusiastic: Take a look at your JSON. If it's an equivalent to what you posted in your question (but in JSON format), you'd want `msg[0].poll`, because the top level of your data structure is an array, whereas `poll` is a property on the first entry in the array.