# Converting PHP array to Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best method for converting a PHP array to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387149/best-method-for-converting-a-php-array-to-javascript)

I am trying something like this:

```
<script>
  var product_name = new array();
  <?php
    foreach($products as $key=>$value) {
      echo "product_name[] = $key";
    }
  ?>
</script>
```

But I could not convert the PHP array to a Javascript array.

Comment: Look for `json_encode()` instead :)

Comment: @Jack I could not able to regard this question as duplicated question. It allow us to demonstrate the topic of the older question in more simple and easy way.

Comment: @Jack Since 2001, before I hear about json, I send my PHP arrays to be client-side arrays for Javascript. It is just how to print the variable.

Comment: @sємsєм What can I say, it's not 2001 anymore :)

Comment: @Jack Simple always remains simple. This is the main idea.

Comment: @sємsєм I'm not going to argue with you about this, take it elsewhere.

Comment: @Jack How can I read json_encode() return result in jQuery ?? Is there any way??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var product_name = new Array();
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($products as $key=>$value)
    {
      echo 'product_name['.$i.'] = '.$key.';';
      $i++;
    }
?>
</script>
```

Better approach would be using json_encode().

Comment: I used your syntax but it is not working.

Comment: I can use json_encode() in php end but how can I use that in javascript end, when I need array key, then I would like to search the values of that array for specific values of that key.

Comment: i've modified a bit. think it'll work now.

Comment: yours one is not working.  
I used the below one  
`
   product_array["<?php echo $i;?>"] = "<?php echo $key;?>"; 
`  

Thanks